# Change Nginx redirection rules based on content-type of request

Tags: nginx

I'm having a reverse-proxied Nginx server. I just wanted to know if it is possible to redirect the request in Nginx based on the content-type of the request?

Right now, I'm checking the URL for a keyword, and based on that, I redirect the request. So it is something like this:

```
location ~*/(keyword){
     proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:6565;
}
```

But now I have another URL having the same keyword. However, the content-type of the request will be `'application/json'`, and I need to forward that request to port 8080. Is it possible to differentiate between these two urls? I'm using Nginx 1.6.2.

Thanks.

Comment: would you mind to share your solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is a messy problem, because the value of the `Accept` header isn't necessarily a single entry, but is instead a list of media types, with "quality" values, which need to be mapped against the available resource representations to determine which type to send back.

There *may* be ways of hacking around with `if` statements and regex matching on the `Accept` header contents (["If is Evil"](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil) notwithstanding), but to do it robustly you're almost certainly going to end up having to write a custom module to do the matching (probably against a map).  There's a third-party [AcceptLanguage](http://wiki.nginx.org/AcceptLanguageModule) module which might contain some useful code to get started.

## Edit based on updated question

If all you want to do is reroute based on the content type of the request body, then life is a lot easier.  I'd setup a [map](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) of content types to backend, then use that map to translate the `$http_content_type` variable into the backend to send the request to.  Make sure you handle (and test!) the "exceptional" cases, such as "didn't send a content-type" and "sent a content-type we didn't expect".

Comment: Thanks, but I actually need to differentiate based on the content-type of the body, so I'm not sure if using the `Accept` directive would work here. I've updated my question.

Comment: Aaaaah... that's a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks, I saw your answer after I figured out the solution. Still have a couple of questions though. I'm mapping based on `$content_type`. Is it different from $http_content_type? Also can I use a variable in the `proxy_pass` directive? This is what I have: `proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:$port;` where $port is the variable I map to based on `$content_type`. Doesn't seem like it is working for me, although $port has the proper value which I need.